# User Adjustable Div Width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, window-resize

I have two React components wrapped in divs side by side. I want to add a bar in the middle that would allow a user to drag left/right and adjust the width of the divs accordingly. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Use mouse events to update the style properties (`width`/`height` or `transform`) of the resizable element node.  Also, it would be ideal to throttle the mouse events, especially if you're using `mousemove` since it fires so frequently.  You might also want to checkout the **[ResizeObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css resize property: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

Or you can use splitter: [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-splitter-layout)
Or you can implement it with js yourself. In this case you will put divs on the borders of the div, catch the mouse click events and recalculate the sizes of your divs. I think it is better to use existing libs.